# Negation of regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have this regular expression:

```
var regex = /^[-.:_A-Za-z0-9]*/;
```

But I need to test a string to see if it has any characters that do **not** match that expression.

I have tried

```
var regex =/^[^-.:_A-Za-z0-9]*$/;
```

But that did not catch the characters that I am looking for.

Basically, I need a regular expression that I can use in javascript to find any character that is not - . : . A-Z a-z or 0-9 in a javascript string variable.

thisShouldPass

thisShou[][]ldFail

Comment: For shortness you can use \w instead of [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: @Bakudan will do, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* you want to remove the anchors and the `*`:

```
var regex =/[^-.:_A-Za-z0-9]/;
```

Comment: No need for the `*`, and in fact, the `*` makes the regex meaningless.

Comment: You don't want the `*` - it will match 0 offending characters.

Comment: Well spotted guys. Sorry. I removed it in my Regex tool but not from the question. My bad.

Comment: You can replace the `_A-Za-z0-9` with just `\w`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response everyone, this will be marked as the answer as soon as I can make it so.

Comment: @wmgeiger101x Awesome :)